# hide popup when click outside by css

Tags: css, dom

For the last couple of years I have been trying to solve my problems in the best way possible, 
and currently trying to solve simple problems by css only if possible, like showing and hiding divs,

The problem now is: showing a popup when click on a button and hide it when click on any where else other than the popup

Comment: if you click on a button it will get focus and active selector, maybe you can e the popup and if you click on the outside the the focus will be lost and you can do display:none

Comment: thanks shiva, that's exactly what I figured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5 minutes ago I found the solution, 
I've been seeing solutions by using check boxes and the :check pseudo selector, 
but it didn't solve this problem,

and found that :focus pseudo selector solved it

CSS:

```
    #btn:focus + label{
        display:block;
    }
    label{
        display:none;
    }
    label:hover{
        display:block;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="btn" value="submit">
<label for="btn">
    <div>
        Popup div
    </div>
</label>
```

putting the popup in a label
so when the button is pressed, the label is visible and the button is focused, when clicking anywhere else, the button is unfocused and label is hidden